# jQuery a click event add class

Tags: jquery, menu, selected

On the `.click` event of the `<a>` element  I adding a class `my-selected-item`.

But the class only affect right at the `.click` event. I read that i can handle this with the function `event.preventDefault`. But this results that the `<a>` element doesn't fire the `href=""` link.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.seaw-menu-item").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass('my-selected-item');
    });
});
```

It seems that I missing a little thing. Thanks for your help!

### EDIT://

It is for a menu purpose.

```
<div class="myMenu">
  <a href="myPage.php?subpage=mySubPage1" class="seaw-menu-item">MenuItem 1</a>
  <a href="myPage.php?subpage=mySubPage2" class="seaw-menu-item">MenuItem 2</a>
  <a href="myPage.php?subpage=mySubPage3" class="seaw-menu-item">MenuItem 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. The code shown will definitely add the class to the clicked element. But then allowing the default means that the page is torn down and replaced by the new page identified by the `href`, so...?

Comment: Mistakenly added this as answer haha,...thing is If you don't want it on click event then why have you added addclass inside the click event function.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder exactly. It is a menu and the `<a>` element are the menu items. With `href=""` i want to load a subpage: `mypage.php?subpage=?mySubPage`

Comment: Please elaborate more on what you actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only guess, but I believe you want something like this:

Add a div with id="someContainer" and the content of the page in the href (assuming same origin) will be loaded into it and the class set

Using your HTML:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("a.seaw-menu-item").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("a.seaw-menu-item").removeClass('my-selected-item'); // remove from all links
        console.log("This would load:"+this.href+" into someContainer");
        $("#someContainer").load(this.href); // load the page
        $(this).addClass('my-selected-item'); // set the class on this link
      });
    });
```

```css
a { text-decoration:none }
a.my-selected-item { text-decoration: underline }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="myMenu">
  <a href="myPage.php?subpage=mySubPage1" class="seaw-menu-item">MenuItem 1</a>
  <a href="myPage.php?subpage=mySubPage2" class="seaw-menu-item">MenuItem 2</a>
  <a href="myPage.php?subpage=mySubPage3" class="seaw-menu-item">MenuItem 3</a>
</div>
<div id="someContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answert but it didnt work. I edited my firstpost to specifiy.

Comment: "It did not work" is not a useful comment. What did not work? Did you implement my suggestion correctly? Did it give console errors, what?

Comment: you helped me with this. I loaded on a click an new php site. But I have to rethink this and use your method loading `div` in to a container.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not very clear but is this what you want?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").on("click", '*:not(a)', function() {
        $(this).addClass('my-selected-item');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com"> the link works </a>
```